# Update query leaving a blank value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to overwrite data in a MySQL table called "login."  I want to replace a field called "website" with the variable $cleanURL.  The code below is what I have tried to use, but the field just ends up blank / empty after I try to use it.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
mysql_query("Update login 
                SET website = $cleanURL 
              WHERE loginid = '$uid'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't quote the $cleanURL variable, or possibly the $uid variable is incorrect.

```
mysql_query("Update login SET website = '$cleanURL' WHERE loginid = '$uid'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing quotes:

try:

```
mysql_query("Update login SET website = '$cleanURL' WHERE loginid = '$uid'");
```

or:

```
mysql_query("Update login SET website = '".$cleanURL."' WHERE loginid = '".$uid."'");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to quote `$cleanURL` which is a `string`. (`$uid` on the other hand is not necessary to be quoted because it is an `integer`)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE login SET website = '$cleanURL' WHERE loginid = $uid");
```